# Python: will having python 2 and python 3 casues trouble?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.6 on my computer,
and I have a file called `first.py` which contains two lines of code:

```
print("hello")
print "hi"
```

and in my command line , I just simply type `first`, and it will print out

```
hello
hi
```

Why is that? I thought print() is a feature of python 3 and would not work for the second line of my code. Also, is it fine for me to have both python versions installed?

Comment: I'm going to guess that 3 isn't installed properly, so this is being evaluated using the 2 interpreter. That's valid code in 2.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Not necessarily. `py.exe` may simply be defaulting to interpreting using 2.7. On 3.6 that shouldn't be the case (in 3.6, failing to specify a version for `py.exe` for an un-shebanged file _should_ go to Py3, in 3.5 and earlier it defaulted to Py2). You'd have to check the file type associations for `.py` files (you want it to be `py.exe`).